# Bounding harmonic functions.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, harmonic-functions

Assume $f, g: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ are harmonic functions.

1. Assume that there exist $C < \infty$ and $\alpha < 1$ such that for all $x$,$$|f(x)| \le C|x|^\alpha.$$What is the easiest way to see that $f$ is constant?
2. Assume that $g(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$. What is the easiest way to see that $g$ is constant?

Comment: Of course the second is trivial with liouville theorem

Comment: @Ant Agree when $d=2,$ but I don't see "trivial" for $d>2.$

Comment: @zhw. why? it was my understanding  it worked for all $d$

Comment: I was thinking the trivial proof was looking at $e^{-u+iv}$ where $u$ is positive and harmonic on $\mathbb R^2.$ Can you sketch the argument that bounded + harmonic = constant implies the same if bounded is replaced by positive, for $d>2$?

Comment: @zhw. From wikipedia: "If $f$ is a harmonic function defined on all of $R^n$ which is bounded above or bounded below, then $f$ is constant ". I took it from there! :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Liouville.27s_theorem

Comment: Ah well, if by definition Liouville includes one-sided boundedness then it is more (less?) than trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Poisson integral formula gives an analogue of "Cauchy's Estimates" in complex analysis: If $f$ is harmonic and $|f(x)|\le M$ for $|x-x_0|=r$ then $$|\nabla f(x_0)|\le c\frac Mr.$$You can use this to show that $\nabla f=0$ in the first question.

The second question is the same, except with a slightly different version of that estimate: The same result holds assuming just that the *average* of $|f(x)|$ on the sphere $|x-x_0|=r$ is no larger than $M$.

Now say $g>0$ is harmonic. The average of $|g(x)|$ for $|x|=r$ is the same as the average of $g(x)$, which is $g(0)$. This shows that $\nabla g(0)=0$. Since any translate of $g$ is also a positive harmonic function, in fact $\nabla g=0$ everywhere.